# Is it possible to add custom buttons to Android actionbar?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm looking to add two buttons for a list and Map like this.

[image: Action bar with List and Map Buttons]

Answer (score 1):

I would use new Toolbar widget, since Toolbar is simply a ViewGroup, you can  add whatever you want:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_id"
   android:layout_width=""
   android:layout_height=""/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You can set a custom view on the ActionVar

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.your_layout);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Comment: with toolbar its easier and faster to use it as custom actionbar view